# Qt .nib issues on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, nib

I'm trying to deploy a Qt C++ application on another mac that doesn't have Qt installed. I am getting a "Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources directory of your application bundle."

I've tried packing qt_menu.lib into both suggested places, with no success:

```
$ ls ./arya.app/Resources/
qt_menu.nib
$ ./arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya 
Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources directory of your application bundle.
```

or:

```
$ mkdir QtGui.framework
$ mkdir QtGui.framework/Versions/
$ mkdir QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/
$ mkdir QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
$ mv ./arya.app/Resources/qt_menu.nib QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
$ ./arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya 
Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources directory of your application bundle.
```

I'm not sure if there may be some connection, but I had some issues with dylib paths before this. After stumbling about with install_name_tool, I 'solved' them with:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

before running the application.

Building the application with

```
CONFIG -= app_bundle
```

made no difference.

Comment: The application runs fine on Windows and Linux, btw.

Comment: Have you tried running `macdeployqt` on your app after you build it?

Comment: @Brendan: No, never heard of it. Looks great for my problem, I'll try it when I get back from my vacation, thanks! Please post a full answer with this suggestion so I can upvote and accept it if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After battling this same problem from another application, I've managed to pin down the exact commands that easily solve this .nib issue:

```
mkdir -p application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Resources
cp -r $(QTLIBDIR)/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Resources/qt_menu.nib application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Resources
```

This does not address other issues on deploying for mac - just the .nib problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

(1) Remove your `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`

(2) Remove your `CONFIG -= app_bundle`

(3) Put QT frameworks into ./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks

I.e. all the contents of *QtGui.framework* into *./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework*,
*QtCore.framework* into *./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework*, etc.

So your qt_menu.nib will automatically be a ./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/qt_menu.nib

Comment: Didn't solve my problem. First I got dylib problems again. After copying the dylibs to . and doind the export DYLD trick again, I was back to where I started:

    $ ./arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya 
    Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. (...)
    $ ls ./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/
    QtCore.framework QtGui.framework  QtNetwork.framework QtOpenGL.framework QtSvg.framework  QtXml.framework
    $ ls ./arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
    qt_menu.nib

Comment: @Fabio: (1) `arya.app` is the name of your bundle. Is that correct? (2) You removed `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`, removed `CONFIG-=app_bundle`, removed all the files generated by `qmake` and `make` including Makefiles, objects, MOC-generated files, UI-generated files, your `arya.app` bundle, etc. leaving only source code and *.pro project file. Right? (3) You compiled your clean project and got `arya.app` bundle with `arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya` binary included. Right? (to be  continued)

Comment: @Fabio (continue): (4) You copied necessary frameworks to `arya.app/Contents/Frameworks` (case-sensitive) and double-checked that their directory structure matches the source (in /Library/Frameworks) including all the symlinks (except headers that you may remove if you like). Right? If all four statements are correct and you really have done all that and it still doesn't work then please post the output of `otool -L arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya` and output of `otool -L arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore` commands.

Comment: Yes, all those steps are automated, even step 4, so that's all taken care of and it was all double and triple-checked. `otool -L` on the application shows hardcoded absolute paths to where the libs were on the dev machine (the application runs fine on the dev machine, btw - it's the QA machine I'm having problems deploying on). I'm on vacation for the next two weeks, but I'll try to get those outputs and post them here next week. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Fabio: "`otool -L` on the application shows hardcoded absolute paths to where the libs were on the dev machine." I see. Then also you have to fix the paths for the application binary and for each Qt binary you deploy. Like this: `install_name_tool -change full_path_ref relative_path_ref target_binary_path` - to change references from absolute paths to relative to your `arya.app/Contents/Frameworks` paths. E.g. `install_name_tool -change /path/to/Qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui arya.app/Contents/MacOS/arya` (to be continued)

Comment: @Fabio (continue): `install_name_tool -change /path/to/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui` - to change QtGui binary to refer to right QtCore and  `install_name_tool -id QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui arya.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui` - to identify QtGui binary with the right id.

Comment: Yeah, I had build steps to run the `install_name_tool -id` and `install_name_tool -change`. It worked ok for the application dependencies, but then it told me that QtSvg itself had a reference to QtCore, and THAT reference also had a hardcoded absolute path. Then I gave up on install_name_tool for the time being.

Comment: @Fabio: "Then I gave up on install_name_tool for the time being." Well. You shouldn't. You should run it for each and every Qt binary you deploy with your bundle and it is important.

Comment: Well since it was also happening with the Qt libraries themselves, I had no idea how many I'd need to do until I'd fixed all of them. Or if I can install_name_tool on the libraries themselves instead of the executable. But I'll get back to finish that when I come back then (if the suggested macdeployqt doesn't do all that automagically). Thank you so much for your all your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try running [`macdeployqt`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool) on your `.app` after building it. It copies the needed Qt frameworks (and any other needed `dylibs`) into the bundle and fixes up the binary's link paths so it knows to link in Qt from it's own bundle.

(It also has a bug that causes any libraries with paths not ending in `lib/` (like `/opt/local/lib/opencv/cv.lib` to not be copied correctly, but there's a one-line source fix for this)