# Pyqtgraph with anaconda python on MAC gives nib error

Tags: python, macos, qt, nib, anaconda

I'm trying to use the [pyqtgraph](http://pyqtgraph.org/) with anaconda python on Mac os

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun 28 2013, 22:20:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

I installed pyqtgraph with `pip install pyqtgraph`, which seemed to work fine. However, if I run any command from the library I get this error:

```
Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be
placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources
directory of your application bundle.
```

I found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426820/qt-nib-issues-on-macos), which seems to be related to C++ app. In my case I have no application.app folder so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to use `python.app` (or the equivalent `pythonw`) to run the program, instead of just `python`. If `pyqtgraph` installed any commands, you'll need to edit them so that their shebang line calls `#!/path/to/anaconda/bin/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python`.