# ipython + qt on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, qt, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

I'm trying to get ipython running with a qt matplotlib backend on Mac OS X 10.9 using [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).

If I try the straightforward approach, I get an error:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.plot()

Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in the resources directory of your application bundle.
Abort trap: 6
```

If I use `python.app` instead of `ipython`, I am able to get a qt window up, but it won't plot anything.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824693/pyqtgraph-with-anaconda-python-on-mac-gives-nib-error) reports a similar error, but the answer posted there doesn't work.  IPython won't even run if the shebang call uses `pythonw` or `python.app`; it claims a syntax error: `line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

So, how do I get ipython + matplotlib + qt running?

Comment: My uninformed guess is that you have installation versions/paths crossed.  It does not look like `qt_menue.nib` is supplied by matplotlib.

Comment: In IPython use `%matplotlib` instead of `matplotlib.use`.

Comment: asmeurer: identical error